# what APIs are used to get command line arguments

Tags: c, api

I have a few questions about which APIs take command line arguments? through debugging with x64dbg. I see funcs like **<GetCommandLineA>**, **<GetCommandLineW>**, or **<&__p__argc>** and **<&__p__argv>**. What is really the API that takes command line argument data?
Sorry for my confusing expression, I don't know English so I have to use google translate :>

Comment: Some tools build on `argc`, `argv` arguments to main. These make the very basic API (`int main(int argc, char **argv)`).

Comment: yes, maybe. however i am looking for something low level like machine code for example. what are those APIs, in which **.dll** file, etc....

Comment: The code in the Standard Library, invoked before `main()` in hosted implementations, is responsible for populating `argc` and `argv`. It depends on your specific compiler/OS. In free-standing implementations, there is no API.

Comment: `low level like machine code for example. what are those API` Then machine code _for which machine_? You might want to research `crt0`.

Answer (score 0):

The C language mandates that command line arguments are available as parameters of the `main` function: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` where:

- argc is the number of non null elements of the `argv` array
- argv points to an array of at least `argc+1` char pointers, the first `argc` ones points to the individual arguments, the last one (`argv[argc]`) being a NULL. By convention, the first argument `argv[0]` should be the command name itself

But in Windows, GUI programs normally have no `main` function but a `WinMain` (ANSI strings version) or `wWinMain` (UNICODE strings version) with unrelated arguments ([ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point)). In that case, the unsplitted command line can be extracted with the (Win32) API functions `GetCommandLineA` (ANSI) or `GetCommandLineW` (UNICODE). In fact real world programs only use `GetCommandLine` which is *an alias which automatically selects the ANSI or Unicode version of this function based on the definition of the UNICODE preprocessor constant* ([ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea)).

If you want to split the command line, only an unicode API is available: [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw).